# answer Concurrent PHP and MySQL request

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue with my php and mysql script, the purpose of posted code is to insert the information in the results in the database results, and while inserting here is the error I am getting.

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE [22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'Array' for column `app_sms`.`results`.`id_message`.

and here is my code.

```
$requete=$pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO resultats VALUES(null, :statut_resultat, :date_debut_resultat, :date_fin_resultat, :examen_resultat, :id_contact, :id_message)');

$requete->bindValue(':statut_resultat',$statut_resultat,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$requete->bindValue(':date_debut_resultat',$date_debut_resultat,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$requete->bindValue(':date_fin_resultat',$date_fin_resultat,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$requete->bindValue(':examen_resultat',$examen_resultat,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$requete->bindValue(':id_contact',$nom_prenom_contact,PDO::PARAM_INT);

$requete->bindValue(':id_message',$okrecuperer,PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: `$okrecuperer` is an array, not an integer. Figure out what it contains and what you should be passing in